# Dynamically setting & removing TRANSLUCENT Status bar flag

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm developing app which runs on Android Lollipop. I have set the status bar color using the following code.

First I set this flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` & then...

`getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);`

But my app requires dynamically set `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` but when I set this flag, it perfectly works showing Transparent Status Bar. Later when I want to color the status bar back, the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` flag doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Use the following to add or remove `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` flag:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);            
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloring the status bar is enabled as default when your app is running on Lollipop and your activity theme inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

AFAIK the `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` is only necessary to color the status bar on Android KitKat.

So in your case, you can simply use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(yourColor);
}
```

in your activity with any color you like (including black of course ;) )